# unity .txt file to cstring

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I need to have a UI Text object display from a .txt file like a book.  It needs to work like a book, so I just have two separate UI Text objects side by side to act like pages, then arrows that are buttons on each one for next page and previous page.  I need to parse a .txt file (I'm trying to use C-Strings so I would populate an array of strings from the .txt file not sure if that is the best route?) every 300 characters because that is the max amount that will fit on the small Text object that was scaled down to look like a real book.

So I need to parse a giant .txt file, say 10,000 characters as an example, into groups of 300 characters.  Then each of those groups of 300 characters would be in it's own array to act like a page.  I have been able to display the .txt file on the UI Text object but the parsing is the big problem.  When the user clicks the next button, after the title page, it would display page1 and page2 then so on and so forth.  Can anyone help or lend a suggestion I'm alone in this development anything would really help.

Comment: You'll surely find answers to this using your favorite search engine. You're not parsing anything, you're *reading all text in a file*, then *splitting into blocks* of specific size. Those are very basic operations and explained on a lot of sites and tutorials.

Comment: Wow that is so enlightening i never would of though of that.  People like you are the reason why newcomers to Stack Overflow avoid it.  How about encouraging people and not making them feel stupid

Comment: The comment was not to make anyone feel stupid, just to explain how you will find the information. We don't write code for you and your question is too broad to fit here. You can read from the help section on how to ask and what is suitable here and what is not. It will help you understand what the idea behind this site is. It is to get help with specific programming problems and usually with something you have already tried. If you want to discuss, for that there are other sites available.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?777441-Split-String-into-multiple-strings-with-a-character-limit-w-out-splitting-words)

Translated version for C#. I'm sure it could be optimized, but should do the trick.

```
public static IList<string> ChunkText(string text, int characterLimit)
{
    List<string> parts = new List<string>();

    while (text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (text.Length <= characterLimit)
        {
            parts.Add(text);
            text = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            int length = characterLimit;
            while (char.IsLetter(text[length])
                    && char.IsLetter(text[length - 1]))
            {
                length--;
            }

            parts.Add(text.Substring(0, length).Trim());
            text = text.Substring(length);
        }
    }

    return parts;
}


static void Main()
{
    string text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    IList<string> parts = ChunkText(text, 10);
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(part);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a real answer with some help I will try this out.